# mysql select sum of values just for distinct rows and filling missing rows resulting from an inner join with group by

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

For my charter reservations system, I am  implementing a `tour` table to store the possible tours and a `booking` table of the bookings done.

Let me simplify it just to put a simpler question. Supose the following.

The `tour` table has a `starts` timestamp and a `seats` integer for the maximum number of possible bookings.

The `booking` table has a `tour` foreign key to the `tour.id` a `client` varchar name and a `pax` integer for the number of reserved seats.

I fill the tables with random values like ...

```
  INSERT INTO booking (tour,client,pax) VALUES 
    (FLOOR(20000 + (RAND() * 100)), MD5(RAND()), FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 5) ));
```

See this DB Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wmwkZ4JSj6geH6TVS4Tsxr/2

Once setup, I can get my bookings for every tour of a given date

```
SELECT tour.id, count(booking.id) as parties, sum(booking.pax) as pax 
    FROM booking INNER JOIN tour ON tour.id = booking.tour 
    WHERE DATE(tour.starts)='2023-12-01'
    GROUP BY tour.id;
```

or for a range of dates

```
SELECT tour.id, DATE(tour.starts) AS date, COUNT(booking.id) AS parties, SUM(booking.pax) AS pax 
  FROM booking INNER JOIN tour ON tour.id = booking.tour 
  WHERE date(tour.starts) BETWEEN '2023-12-01' AND '2023-12-14'
  GROUP BY tour.id
  ORDER BY tour.starts;
```

so far, so good.

I need to build an availability calendar, so I want to group, not by tour but by date
to have an overview of availability for each day

```
SELECT DATE(tour.starts) AS date, COUNT(DISTINCT tour.id) as tours, COUNT(booking.id) AS parties, 
SUM(booking.pax) pax, SUM(tour.seats) - SUM(booking.pax) AS available 
  FROM booking INNER JOIN tour ON tour.id = booking.tour 
  WHERE DATE(tour.starts) BETWEEN '2023-12-01' AND '2023-12-14'
  GROUP BY DATE(tour.starts)
  ORDER BY date;
```

but this query has two problems

Problem 1: The availability is not calculated correctly, because it adds all tour.seats for as many bookings each tour has. I would like to just sum the seats for the distinct tours. Something like my invented new statement SUM(tour.seats FOR DISTINCT tour.id).

Problem 2: The tours that dont have any booking don't appear. If a date had just bookings for one tour, the other tours would'nt sum their seats as available (supposing we solve problem #1). And if there are no bookings for a date, that date will not appear at all. However, there are tours and seats available.

Any ideas on how to solve this issues?

Comment: Problem 2: Maybe change `FROM booking INNER JOIN tour ON tour.id = booking.tour` to `FROM tour LEFT JOIN booking ON tour.id = booking.tour`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this in two stages, using a subselect.  In the inner select, group by tour.id and add the booking information per tour:

```
SELECT
  tour.id AS id,
  DATE(tour.starts) AS date,
  IFNULL(COUNT(booking.id), 0) AS parties, 
  IFNULL(SUM(booking.pax), 0) AS pax,
  tour.seats - IFNULL(SUM(booking.pax), 0) AS available 
FROM tour
LEFT JOIN booking ON tour.id = booking.tour 
WHERE DATE(tour.starts) BETWEEN '2023-12-01' AND '2023-12-14'
GROUP BY tour.id
```

Then wrap this in an outer select to get the summary by date.  NB I added the `GREATEST` function so that overbooked tours don't reduce the availability for underbooked tours.

```
  SELECT
    date,
    COUNT(id) AS tours,
    SUM(parties) AS parties,
    SUM(pax) AS pax,
    SUM(GREATEST(available, 0)) AS available
  FROM (
    SELECT
      tour.id AS id,
      DATE(tour.starts) AS date,
      IFNULL(COUNT(booking.id), 0) AS parties, 
      IFNULL(SUM(booking.pax), 0) AS pax,
      tour.seats - IFNULL(SUM(booking.pax), 0) AS available 
    FROM tour
    LEFT JOIN booking ON tour.id = booking.tour 
    WHERE DATE(tour.starts) BETWEEN '2023-12-01' AND '2023-12-14'
    GROUP BY tour.id
  ) t
  GROUP BY t.date
  ORDER BY t.date
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! LEFT JOIN was indeed the spark I needed to start moving my thinking in the right direction.  (how did I miss it? that's a question for another StackExchange forum)